# M4: Is it possible to access bash env vars from within m4 script?

Tags: bash, m4

Suppose I define:

```
$: export my_setting="whatever"
```

Next, I open up my `foo.m4` and write (**pseudocode**, for illustrative purposes):

```
define(__SETTING__,${my_setting})
```

This would be pretty useful, because now I can hide away my m4.  But how would one go about accessing environment vars from the `.m4` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$> cat my.m4
qux

$> ( export foo=bar; m4 "-Dqux=${foo}" my.m4 )
```

Comment: but not necessarily access a host of vars? Just a la carte via command line?

Comment: I had a quick look through the m4 manual and it looks like `-D` is your best bet. ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/m4/html_chapter/m4_toc.html